# Data output using javascript in codeidnater 3

Tags: javascript, php

I have a date field. It is necessary that when choosing a date under this field, the div is displayed using Javascript, this is the date.
Send the goal using javascript to the controller.
I need this code as a basis for other purposes. Help if you can
View

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control ium_textbox" name="date_sched" value="" id="date_a" required>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date_a').change(function () {
        var time = $(".ium_textbox").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:<?= base_url() ?>"application/controllers/frontend/get_datetime",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {date: time},
            success: (function (data) {
                 $("#date_field").html(data);
            })
        });         
    });
});
```

Controller

```
   public function get_datetime()
{
  $this->load->view('frontend/get_datetime');
      }
```

get_datetime.php

```
<? echo $_POST['date'] ?>
```

Comment: Url param that you provided in AJAX call doesn't seem to be a proper Javascript syntax. Could you share what happens when function get executed?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are calling should be in the same form as if you were calling it directly via the web browser.

**A Side NOTE:** You can prevent direct access if you only want it accessed via an AJAX call and not directly from the browser by using `$this->load->is_ajax_request()`. Something you may want to look up

So, if the controller is called Frontend and the method is get_datetime, then your AJAX Url should be

```
// Line to change in AJAX Call
url:<?= base_url() ?>"frontend/get_datetime",
```

Make sure you have configured base_url correctly.
I.E under **/application/config/config.php** ensure

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://your_domain_name.com/';
```

Changing http://your_domain_name.com/ to suit your actual domain name.
**Note:** The trailing / on the URL.

**For extra debug** you can add in some console.log(); into your javascript and view the results in your Browsers Dev Tools - Console Tab.

I.E if you want to make sure that time is being set correctly you can...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date_a').change(function () {
        var time = $(".ium_textbox").val();

        // Added Debug
        console.log('The Time is : ' + time);

        $.ajax({
            url:<?= base_url() ?>"frontend/get_datetime",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {date: time},
            success: (function (data) {
                 $("#date_field").html(data);
            })
        });         
    });
});
```

So I hope that helps.
It's important to learn how to debug your code to see what it's actually doing. So that's a start.